# React native как запустить чужой проект?

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, npm, react-native

скачал сборку с гитхаба и хотел бы проверить ее у себя, но проблема не устанавливается - собака ...  что я делал ?

1. скачал и в рабочую папку скопировал проект react native
2. после этого в VS CODE я открываю cmd в проекте
3. ввожу npm install
4. npm install -> посылает меня на!#$!$%

дает вот такую ошибку ... и не знаю как установить

---

подскажите как запустить ?

```
d:\JS\tutorialProject>npm install npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7:
 core-js@<2.6.5 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3
 or at least to actual version of core-js@2. npm WARN deprecated
 connect@2.30.2: connect 2.x series is deprecated npm ERR! path
 d:\JS\tutorialProject\node_modules\.bin\react-native npm ERR! code
 EEXIST npm ERR! Refusing to delete
 d:\JS\tutorialProject\node_modules\.bin\react-native: is outside
 d:\JS\tutorialProject\node_modules\react-native and not a link npm
 ERR! File exists: d:\JS\tutorialProject\node_modules\.bin\react-native
 npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
 C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-16T18_15_13_614Z-debug.log
```

[Нажми на меня и увидишь про какой проект говорит автор](https://github.com/sunlight3d/react_native_v0.49/tree/master/61-Realm%20React%20Native%235.Filter%20data%20and%20working%20with%20To-Many%20Relationships/code/tutorialProject)

Comment: Не увидел, что говорит автор по этому поводу. По поводу ошибки - попробуйте в package.json изменить версию `core-js` на 2.6.5 и `connect` на последнюю (@latest)

Comment: Для начала попробуйте удалить папку node_modules

Comment: Ivan Kramarchuk -> удалял и пересобирал, на моменте start-android , был краш билда (bild filed), так что удалить node_modules не вариант ...

Comment: Stepan Kasyanenko -> в package.json  нету ни core ни connect